# python re.match doesn't work for a multipleline text file

Tags: python, regex

I would like to write a Python program that searches and saves the vocabulary definition of an English word.

I have converted a Babylon English-Italian dictionary into a text file.

I would like that `re.match()` matches **the first word of each line**, but it doesn't.

I get always: 'not found', namely `None` for any query (word copied in my code) I use.

The Babylon text file can be found here:
https://tempfile.io/en/ba2voaBnDJsn24P/file

Thanks

```
import clipboard
import json
import re

wordcopied = clipboard.paste()
print(wordcopied)
dictionary = {}

with open("/home/user/Babylon-EI.txt", "r") as source:
    lsource = source.readlines()
    for line in lsource:
        #print(type(line))
        matc = re.match(wordcopied, line, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
        if matc != None:
            print(line)
            dictionary = {wordcopied:line}
        else:
            print('not found')
            break
```

I've tried also with re.search, and with multiple flags..
Related questions are all answered regarding flags and blanks

Comment: `re.match` only searches at the start of the string, use `re.search`. And `re.escape` the word if it is a literal string.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i already tried re.search.
my goal is to in fact find the match at the beginning of each line. 
I have already done a search on similar issues but these doesn't fit properly my case.

Comment: The `if matc != None:` looks suspicious, why not just use `if matc:`?

Comment: Seem your codes search the word one line at a time in a loop and if the first line fails, your codes would break the loop.  Probably what you meant is matc = re.match(wordcopied, lsource, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL) (without the for loop)

Comment: Yes! Shiping! you are right! it was the else statement! what a dummy was I! I beg your pardon!